# How to define custom locating strategy for select

Tags: ruby, gwt, watir, page-object-gem

I looking for a proper way to redefine/extend locating strategy for select tag in Gwt app. 
From html snippet you can see that `select` tag is not visible.
So to select option from list I need to click on `button` tag, and than select needed `li` tag from dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="bootstrap-select form-control" style="display: none; locator='gender">
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" title="Male">
      <div class="dropdown-menu open">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
          <li data-original-index="1"> (contains a>span with option text)
            .....more options
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see dirty solution: to implement method in BasePage class. This approach nice page_object sugar(options,get value, etc):

```
def set_nationality(country, nationality='Nationality')
  select = button_element(xpath: "//button[@title='#{nationality}']")
  select.click
  option = span_element(xpath: "//span[.='#{country}']")
  option.when_visible
  option.click
end
```

Is there any other more clear way to do so? Using `PageObject::Widgets maybe?

UPD: Here what I expect to get:

```
def bool_list(name, identifier={:index => 0}, &block)
  define_method("#{name}_btn_element") do
    platform.send('button_for', identifier.clone + "//button")
  end
  define_method("#{name}?") do
    platform.send('button_for', identifier.clone + "//button").exists?
  end
  define_method(name) do
    return platform.select_list_value_for identifier.clone + '/select' unless block_given?
    self.send("#{name}_element").value
  end
  define_method("#{name}=") do |value|
    return platform.select_list_value_set(identifier.clone + '/select', value) unless block_given?
    self.send("#{name}_element").select(value)
  end
  define_method("#{name}_options") do
    element = self.send("#{name}_element")
    (element && element.options) ? element.options.collect(&:text) : []
  end
end
```

Comment: If you only have one of these controls, a method in the BasePage is not terrible. However, if you use similar controls throughout the application, using the PageObject::Widgets will greatly improve the maintainability of your code. There are a couple of examples online ([gwt_widgets](https://rubygems.org/gems/gwt_widgets/versions/0.0.7) and [gwt-widgets](https://github.com/snowe2010/gwt-widgets)), however neither seems to cover your exact dropdown.

Comment: That's why I'm looking for a way to implement widget fro this case. Main problem - it's not clear (from docs or examples) how to redefine location strategy for ::Accessors or add custom logic

Comment: What do you mean by "redefine location strategy"? An example of what you have tried and where it is that you are stuck would help.

Comment: @JustinKo I've just updated description. these are methods which I would like to get. I'm not sure that will work, as select tag is hidden. so to select it actually need to interact with button>ul tags. any advices will be helpful

Comment: The starting point should be figuring out how to relate the elements of the same control together. Do you have a page where 2 of these types of select lists exist - for example is there a page that shows both the gender and nationality select lists? If there is, can you share the HTML?

Comment: @JustinKo Here you can find html of these select lists: http://pastebin.com/t7p9qC5Z
And here is screenshot how it should look like: http://take.ms/h3V44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select list appears to have the most identify attributes, therefore I would use it as the base element of the widget. All of the other elements, ie the button and list items, would need to be located with respect to the select list. In this case, they all share the same `div.form-group` ancestor.

The widget could be defined as:

```
class BoolList < PageObject::Elements::SelectList
  def select(value)
    dropdown_toggle_element.click
    option = span_element(xpath: "./..//span[.='#{value}']")
    option.when_visible
    option.click
  end

  def dropdown_toggle_element
    button_element(xpath: './../div/button')
  end

  def self.accessor_methods(widget, name)
    widget.send('define_method', "#{name}_btn_element") do
      self.send("#{name}_element").dropdown_toggle_element
    end

    widget.send('define_method', "#{name}?") do
      self.send("#{name}_btn_element").exists?
    end

    widget.send('define_method', name) do
      self.send("#{name}_element").value
    end

    widget.send('define_method', "#{name}=") do |value|
      self.send("#{name}_element").select(value)
    end

    widget.send('define_method', "#{name}_options") do
      # Since the element is not displayed, we need to check the inner HTML
      element = self.send("#{name}_element")
      (element && element.options) ? element.options.map { |o| o.element.inner_html } : []
    end
  end
end
PageObject.register_widget :bool_list, BoolList, :select
```

Notice that all locators are in relation to the select list. As well, notice that we use the `accessor_methods` to add the extra methods to the page object.

The page object would then use the `bool_list` accessor method. Note that the identifier is for locating the select element, which we said would be the base element of the widget.

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  bool_list(:gender, title: 'Gender')
  bool_list(:nationality, title: 'Nationality')
end
```

The page will now be able to call the following methods:

```
page.gender_btn_element.click
page.gender_btn_element.exists?
page.gender
page.gender = 'Female'
page.gender_options

page.nationality_btn_element.click
page.nationality_btn_element.exists?
page.nationality
page.nationality = 'Barbados'
page.nationality_options
```